# Change from single target to last used cell in column

Tags: excel, powershell, copy-paste

I am sure this is a common question.  I am trying to just paste instead of to the target cell in the paste range, to go to the `last used cell in the column + 1`, so it just appends the target spread sheet.  What do I need to change here?

I have tried some of the suggestions on here but keep getting errors, probably because I am using `$lastRow = $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.rows.count + 1` in the wrong place (haven't been using powershell that long).

If anyone can show easiest way to do this would be great.  Thanks!

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$Excel.Visible=$true 

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($pathxlsx)
$TempWorkbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Opentext($pathcsv)

$temp = $excel.Workbooks.Item(2)  
$temp = $temp.Worksheets.Item(1)
$CopyRange = $temp.Range("C15") 
$CopyRange.Copy()  

$workbooksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1)
$Workbooksheet.activate()
$PasteRange = $workbooksheet.Range("C10")
$workbooksheet.Paste($PasteRange)
```

EDIT - Ok, got it to do something different, but still not what I want.

```
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject "Excel.Application"
$Excel.Visible=$true 

$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($pathxlsx) 
$TempWorkbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Opentext($pathcsv) 

$temp = $excel.Workbooks.Item(2)  
$temp = $temp.Worksheets.Item(1) 
$CopyRange = $temp.Range("C15") 
$CopyRange.Copy()  

$workbooksheet = $Workbook.Worksheets.Item(1) 
$ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.rows.count
$lastRow = $workbooksheet.UsedRange.rows.count + 1
$Workbooksheet.activate()
$PasteRange = $workbooksheet.Range("C" + $lastrow) 
$workbooksheet.Paste($PasteRange)
```

Comment: I don't know too much about `powershell` but after your `$CopyRange.Copy()` line, can you try this: '$workbooksheet.Range("C"& $workbooksheet.Range("C" & $workbooksheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row + 1)`. Note, in VBA `&` sign is used to build a string. Not sure what the equivalent of that is in `powershell` but you might have to change that

Comment: `$lastRow = $ExcelWorkSheet.UsedRange.rows.count + 1` - how exactly have you been using this?

Comment: Something like this: `$lastRow = $workbooksheet.UsedRange.rows.count + 1 $PasteRange = $workbooksheet.Range("C"+$lastrow) $workbooksheet.Paste($PasteRange)`

Comment: It's not pasting to the last used +1 still.  Pasting to line 170?!?

Comment: Still have no idea why it continually pastes to line 170?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just creating an excel template with a power query for this issue.   This plus a formula to transpose the data allowed for a clean copy and paste with the data I needed in the form i needed it.